# segue from a third view

Tags: uistoryboard, uistoryboardsegue

I am currently working on a storyboard app. I have 3 file. appdelegate, Login view and register view.

In login view I have a button FB login and register button. On regiter button I am pushing register view. It is working fine.

I am calling `getfbinfo()` on registerFB. `getfbinfo()` is in appdelegate. When I have got user FB info then I want to push to register view. I have tried to call register button function from login view but it is crashing. I have seen some links. but I am unable to find a solution.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Could you give us what's your language (C# with Xamarin?) Could you also give us the error message?

Comment: Language in objective c. it is showing error message Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Receiver (<LoginViewController: 0x99306f0>) has no segue with identifier '1''

Comment: You didn't set/named a segue in StoryBoard with "1".

Comment: github.com/mayankpurwar/testFB you can see this link. I have made a test project for it.

Comment: @MayankPurwar do you know how to code this in swift 2.0. I am following youtube.com/watch?v=PKOswUE731c and i am also stuck with a register button on my login view. If i hit it it crashes the app and i get the message 'Receiver (<registerLogin.RegisterViewController: 0x7f97235f6140>) has no segue with identifier 'loginView''

Answer (score 2):

In storyboard, give your segue (from button to view controller) an identifier.
Then (assuming that you have a proper reference to your login view controller in the App delegate) call

```
[loginViewController performSegueWithIdentifier:@"your_storyboard_identifier" sender:nil]
```

when FB login completes.

Comment: I am using code  LoginViewController *login = [LoginViewController alloc];
                 
                 [login performSegueWithIdentifier:@"1" sender:nil];  but it is crashing again with Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Receiver (<LoginViewController: 0x99306f0>) has no segue with identifier '1''

Comment: did you set "1" as segue identifier in storyboard to your segue (from login to the next one?)

Comment: https://github.com/mayankpurwar/testFB  you can see this link. I have made a test project for it.

Comment: sorry, didn't read your code well... why would you need to alloc a new LoginViewController? Of course it doesn't have a segue, it's created with code at runtime, it's not the same instance "automatically" created by the storyboard. If you are in the app delegate, you need to find a way to get a reference to that view controller (I assumed you already had one), you can't just create it like that... That's why I wrote "assuming that you have a proper reference to your login view controller in the App delegate" in my very first answer.

Comment: I've submitted you a pull request on your github that should fix your problem. Unfortunately, your FacebookApp (in developers.facebook.com) doesn't allow me to login, but it should work for you.